# How to create custom Tensorflow Graph from Binary Encoding of NN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I would like to create a custom Tensorflow topology, specifically a custom Tensorflow topology out of a binary encoding of a neural network. I have attached a picture of what I mean by 'binary encoding of a neural network' below.

[Binary Encoding of ANN (Source: Yao99)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikuAk.png)

Unfortunately am I only familiar with how to use Tensorflow using complete layers, mostly via the Keras API, though I don't know how to create the whole topology in a custom way from scratch.

I don't require a complete solution, but would already highly appreciate links to tutorials on how to create such custom topologies from scratch. The final translation on how to map the binary encoding to the custom graph creation I can do myself. Unfortunately am I unable to find resources for such custom topologies online. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think this is the paper that you are referring to: http://avellano.fis.usal.es/~lalonso/compt_soft/articulos/yao99evolving.pdf. Can you please confirm ?

Comment: Yes that is the paper I am referring to. I didn't supply it since the research in this paper is not applicable to my question or project. I just needed a good illustration example for a binary encoding representing a NN.